# Oracle pl/sql type

Tags: oracle10g

is it possible to have some oracle objects like collections in memory than populated and use it in other pl/sql blocks? something like:

```
create type myType as objects
(id number, name varchar2(40));
create type myTabType is table of myType;
procedure populateMyTabType is
   vType myTabType := myTabType();
begin
   for i in (select id,name
             from employees) loop
         vType.extend;
         vType(vType.last) := myType(i.id, i.name);
   end loop;
end;
```

and now I would like throgh a pl/sql block to iterate through myTabType.
can I do this? how?

Thank you

Comment: What do you want to do? I don't understand, If you want to iterate over the `vType` variable use `FOR i IN vType.FIRST..vType.LAST LOOP ... END LOOP;`

Comment: yes, but I would like to populate it, than through another pl/sql to iteate through it. I mean after I run the procedure, than from a different pl/sql block to iterate through the collection as you said.

Answer (score 0):

For example like this:

```
create type myType as object
(id number, name varchar2(40));
create type myTabType is table of myType;

create or replace function populateMyTabType 
return myTabType
is
   vType myTabType := myTabType();
begin
  for i in (select 1 id,'name' name
              from dual) loop
         vType.extend;
         vType(vType.COUNT) := myType(i.id, i.name);
  end loop;
  return vType;
end populateMyTabType;

create or replace procedure iterateMyTabType(
  p_mytype IN myTabType
)
is
begin
  for i in p_mytype.FIRST..p_mytype.LAST
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(p_mytype(i).id || ' ' || p_mytype(i).name);
  end loop;
end iterateMyTabType;

begin
  iterateMyTabType(populateMyTabType);
end;

1 name
```

But you need to use [`bulk collect into`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html) if you can.

PS: pay attention I changed the `select` statement in the `for` clause in the `populateMyTabType` you need to use your own select.